# display tree structure from custom sharepoint list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sharepoint

I would like construct treeview structure from custom Sharepoint 2010 List. Could you please let me know if there are any examples or any ideas? I appreciate any help.

Comment: How are you accessing your data? Api, Client Object, ...?

Answer (score 0):

Search the Internet for *sharepoint list tree view* and you'll get lots of results - you can [buy appropriate Web Part](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/p-38-tree-view-web-part.aspx), [get a free one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/librarytreewebpart.aspx) and [build your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597539.aspx).